# Visual studio deployment setup:disable installation folder selection dialog

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

Is it possible to disable the installation folder selection dialog.
Are there any settings in visual studio 2010 which accomplish this during creation of setup and deployment projects?

Thanks in advance,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply delete it:

- select your setup project in Solution Explorer
- go to its User Interface Editor
- delete **Installation Folder** item under "Install" -> "Start"

Comment: This page have to good small tutorial about too. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/437285/Visual-Studio-Deployment-Setup-Disable-Installatio